# unable to get alert-notifications or dashboards from Grafana API

Tags: api, grafana

What happened:
trying to export alert notifications, data-sources and dashboard through API but only getting [] with /api/alert-notifications and only receiving dashboards folder names with /api/dashboards, data-source getting all information with /api/datasources/

What you expected to happen:

expecting to get every alert notifications with there parameters and dashboards information

How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):

fresh helm grafana installation with any dashboard, data source or alert notification

Anything else we need to know?:

tried with api key auth, user/passwiord auth, with different orgs, different permitions etc...

Environment:

```
Grafana version: open source 8.5.3
Data source type & version: prometheus 2.34.0/ loki 2.4.2
OS Grafana is installed on: helm installation
User OS & Browser: manjaro kde, curl/postman
Grafana plugins: json
```